# GitHub Pages: redirect the old project URL to the new one

Tags: github, redirect, github-pages

Suppose I have a project `project-old`, that uses GitHubPages and I created a brand new version of it: `project-new`..

Now, the `project-new` is tested and ready to "production", is there a way before archiving the `project-old`, located at the page
 `https://example.com/project-old`

to redirect the visitors to the

`https://example.com/project-new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, considering any automatic redirection is done by GitHub only when [you rename a project](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/renaming-a-repository).

... Except for PAges:

> When you rename a repository, all existing information, with the exception of project site URLs, is automatically redirected to the new name
>
> If you plan to rename a repository that has a GitHub Pages site, we recommend using a custom domain for your site. This ensures that the site's URL isn't impacted by renaming the repository

In your case, referring to the pages of your old or new project through [a custom domain](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages) would be easier.

You can then go on and make later a new-new project, without having to worry about URL changes.

---

If this is not convenient, then see "[Setup a redirect on Github Pages](https://dev.to/steveblue/setup-a-redirect-on-github-pages-1ok7) " from [Steve Belovarich](http://twitter.com/iplayitofflegit), using an `index.html` (in your old project) with a redirect instruction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Redirecting to https://example.com/</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://example.com/">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't really understand what exactly to do in your first case. I have a custom domain, so what should I do to redirect visitors from /old-path to the /new-path? I will try your second solution, because I don't understand the first one

Comment: @Serge The first one means simply to change the URL references by your current custom domain from old to new project (https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site)